# Really weird AJAX behavior (problems sending correct request type)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

We have a web application built up on a Laravel 5 framework. We have many Routes set up (either POST or GET routes), we have many of them being called by AJAX methods and everything seemed to work fine until today.

We tried to create a new post route

```
Route::post('ip_filters_company', [
    'as' => 'ipFiltersCompany',
    'uses' => 'App\SettingsController@ipFiltersCompany'
]);
```

and tried to call it by jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST", // we tried also type: "POST"
    url: "ip_filters_company", // we tried also "/ip_filters_company", "ip_filters_company/", "/ip_filters_company/"
    data: 'test'
});
```

we also tried to simplify it as in:

```
$.post("ip_filters_company"); // again with different "slashed" modifications
```

Strangely, all our attempted `POST` requests to this new route were sent as `GET` request while we were receiving `405 error (Method not allowed)` and we could see in Chrome's Network tab that `POST` is required (we tried to send it as `POST`, js sent `GET` and server failed to serve since it wanted `POST`).

We found out that other routes such as

```
Route::post('rename_company', [
    'as' => 'renameCompany',
    'uses' => 'App\CompaniesController@renameCompany'
]);
```

could be called without any problems using

```
$.post("rename_company");
```

So we tried to rewrite the last mentioned (and working) route to

```
Route::post('rename_company2', [
    'as' => 'renameCompany2',
    'uses' => 'App\CompaniesController@renameCompany'
]);
```

and call it with

```
$.post("rename_company2");
```

and it failed with 405 error. (but why?)

We also tried to delete all other routes defined in laravel but to no help. (we also cleared route cache of laravel)

To sum it up so far, we cannot apparently add new route accessible with `POST` (strange, isn't it?)

We decided that the problem might be caused by jQuery version, so we tried  3 of them - 2.1.1, 1.11.3 and 1.4.4. (didn't help).

Then we decided the problem is caused by jQuery itself so we tried this:

```
(function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { console.log(arguments) };
    xhr.open("POST", "ip_filters_company", false);
    xhr.send();
})();
```

which amazed us even more:

[image: although post is required, post is not allowed]

As you can see the `POST` is required and sent - but not allowed.

We would really appreciate any help in this problem. Could someone please explain what could be causing these problems and how to fix them?

Comment: This has to be an issue in your controller, providing you are setting the request type in jquery and the trailing slash is present, it will send the correct HTTP method. However your app thinks the route doesn't exist, probably a typo tucked away in the controller somewhere.

Comment: You can also test this by adding a simple GET route on the same url to verify if the request is getting through, regardless of the method.

Comment: Make sure your routes aren't cached. `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: test this action as GET,if it will work then you will understand your error comes for token input

Comment: Thanks for comments everyone...  
@ImtiazPabel: Thank you, you were right :) Your help is really appreciated. We forgot to add it to open routes, it is obvious right now. It is interesting how a tiny detail can go unnoticed... However this reaction of XHR seems to me a little bit misleading. If you will, make an answer from your comment so I can mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this subject I decided to post the answer on my own. Firstly, thanks to all those who commented on the question and helped us with out problem.

We discovered that we forgot to add that route to open routes. Furthermore one of the colleagues did following: If POST request cannot pass (no csrf token, not in open routes), ignore it and redirect to the same page over GET. Therefore if we sent POST request withou csrf token, it automatically changed to GET request and was blocked with 405 error (method not allowed)

TLDR: quick solution was to add that route to open routes.